# Do I have to enable webdav manually for dotCMS?

Tags: webdav, dotcms

On my windows, webdav for dotcms works fine. However, it does not work for my co-worekr's server. He is using linux.

For dotcms, do I have to enable something to use webdav?

Comment: asked dotCMS staff. Answer was "no, you don't have to"

Answer (score 2):

By default it was enabled, check detail from [here](http://dotcms.com/docs/1.9/BulkUploadFilesViaWebdav)

You can access it by two URL links:

`host:port/webdav/autopub` (files are published as they are uploaded)

`host:port/webdav/nonpub` (files uploaded as "working" copies)

BTW, usually, you can download most of items, but when you upload files, you will fail.

Answer (score 0):

No, all you need is a standards compliant client.  OSX users can use finder to connect via webdav.  For Windows users, try BitKinex as a client.  The url should look like

> http://yourserver.com/webdav/autopub